# Failed to compile apk with Android Studio 3.2 + Windows

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I had to switch to Android Studio 3.2 Canary to use the new AndroidX components.

My main development environment is Mac/OSX and everything works fine. However, this week I had to switch to Windows and when compiling the apk I'm getting the below exception.

As I'm using AndroidX, had to enable in gradle.properties file:

- android.enableJetifier=true
- android.useAndroidX=true

Here's the exception.

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\rafael.chagas\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar\a98f8e9d46ed106e8653ab19e7672193\jars\classes.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:877)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$7(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:802)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:872)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: entry
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:346)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ArchiveClassFileProvider.getProgramResource(ArchiveClassFileProvider.java:91)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.r8.CachingArchiveClassFileProvider.lambda$getProgramResource$0(CachingArchiveClassFileProvider.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.r8.CachingArchiveClassFileProvider.getProgramResource(CachingArchiveClassFileProvider.java:38)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.r8.ClassFileProviderFactory$OrderedClassFileResourceProvider.getProgramResource(ClassFileProviderFactory.java:78)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ClassProvider$ClassFileResourceReader.collectClass(ClassProvider.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ClassMap$ConcurrentClassLoader.get(ClassMap.java:241)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ClassMap$ConcurrentClassLoader.get(ClassMap.java:217)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ClassMap.get(ClassMap.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication.definitionFor(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.AppInfo.definitionFor(AppInfo.java:62)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.desugar.InterfaceMethodRewriter.findDefinitionFor(InterfaceMethodRewriter.java:255)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.desugar.InterfaceMethodRewriter.rewriteMethodReferences(InterfaceMethodRewriter.java:140)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.rewriteCode(IRConverter.java:675)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertMethodToDex(IRConverter.java:346)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexClass.forEachMethodThrowing(DexClass.java:132)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.lambda$convertClassesToDex$2(IRConverter.java:332)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:117)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:38)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:260)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:66)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:36)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertClassesToDex(IRConverter.java:330)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertToDex(IRConverter.java:245)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.optimize(D8.java:202)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:162)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.lambda$run$1(D8.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:56)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:41)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:89)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
```

The target .jar file above is random. It may fail with any of the project libraries.

I know that this is a Canary release of Android Studio, but what intrigues me is that this only occurs with Windows OS. Tested in Linux, OSX and had no problems at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue, including jetified-material, jetified-firebase etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the root cause and fix to this issue.

Looking into the error messages, the Android R8 class causing the exception was:
*src/main/java/com/android/tools/r8/ArchiveClassFileProvider.java*

Digging into R8 source i found the latest logs and a brand new commit that changes the encoding while reading .zip files:

https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/a26659a1d07b4dc4ad0c3f8dbafd47d49efbc438

This commit changes the way R8 reads zip archives using UTF-8 encoding and avoid using the platform encoding. That's why only Windows was failing.

I tested the latest R8 release with that commit and it worked! Just need to add these (+) lines to your project **build.gradle** file.

```
 repositories {
     google()
     jcenter()
+    maven {
+        url "http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw"
+    }
 }
dependencies {
+    classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.2.28'
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18'
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
 }
```

The "com.android.tools:r8:1.2.28" **must** be the first one in the dependencies.

According to the [BUG 109992855](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109992855) that new version of R8 will be pushed to Android Studio 3.2 in about two weeks. Meanwhile you must use the above fix.

Hope that helps anyone who stumbled on this error.

Comment: Excellent find and great deep-dive to find the solution :)!